# Hyperlink Columns in the Form and List DotNetNuke Module

Tags: dotnetnuke

The Form and List module for DotNetNuke makes it fairly easy to include a hyperlink as one of the columns.

Unfortunately, it's not so easy to have a different caption for each.

For example, it's simple to get this:

```
Name   Company
-----  ---------
Sue    http://www.apple.com
Fred   http://www.google.com
Joe    http://www.facebook.com
```

What I really want, however, is this (with hyperlinks in the Company column):

```
Name   Company
-----  ---------
Sue    Apple
Fred   Google
Joe    Facebook
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the generate xsl and then modify the xsl to give the layout you want

see explanation and sample xsl [F&L XSL](http://jsfiddle.net/nokiko/CXXP3/)

Comment: This is the approach I would take as well